# Removing div based on the ID not existing in a jQuery AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting rows of content via jQuery AJAX and then populating the table with new content as it is being added. The problem is that some content may be deleted from the database, in which case I also want it removed in real-time from the table.

I suspect I need to loop through the table div IDs and remove any IDs that don't exist in the AJAX response but I'm unsure how to compare them to the data response and then remove them:

```js
function startRecords() {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var res = data;

      for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($("#records-row-" + res[i].id).length == 0) {
          $("#records-content tbody").prepend('<tr class="table-wrapper" id="records-row-' + res[i].id + '"><td class"" style="">' + res[i].content_1 + '</td><td class"" style="">' + res[i].content_2 + '</td></tr>');
        }
      }

      var delay = 3000;
      setTimeout(function() {
        startRecords();
      }, delay);
    },
    cache: false
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    var delay = 3000;
    setTimeout(function() {
      startRecords();
    }, delay);
  });
}
```

Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

Comment: It appears you only append the new content to the table - how do you know if data has been removed? If you're only getting partial data there's no way to know if the missing content is just old data or removed data. You instead need to either have the AJAX return *all* valid data and rebuild the table on each update, or you return new content and deleted content in different arrays of the response, and add/remove the relevant data.

Comment: Also note that making an AJAX request to your server every 3 seconds * number of concurrent users is not a scalable solution. If you need to keep the server side data and client side UI in close sync, I'd suggest looking in to WebSockets or Server Sent Events, and researching the Observer Pattern

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you. I will look into a more scalable solution. For now, not many users will be using it, so it's still somewhat okay. The only way to know that the content has been removed would be if it's not in the response array anymore :/

Comment: If it's a new content that you're receiving, then just replace the old content with the new, no need for appending. but if the content you're receiving should *update* the content in your table, then you can't determine what should be removed, except if the response you receive has information about removed data.

Comment: In which case it would simply be a case of calling `$("#records-content tbody").empty()` before your `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

you are prepending to "records-content" div without clearing it first.
you need to add

`$("#records-content tbody").html('')`

before starting your for loop.
this way only current data in you database table will populate in table.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) to clear the records, before prepending new ones.

```
function startRecords() {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      $("#records-content tbody").empty();

      for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($("#records-row-" + res[i].id).length == 0) {
          $("#records-content tbody").prepend('<tr class="table-wrapper" id="records-row-' + res[i].id + '"><td class"" style="">' + res[i].content_1 + '</td><td class"" style="">' + res[i].content_2 + '</td></tr>');
        }
      }

      var delay = 3000;
      setTimeout(function() {
        startRecords();
      }, delay);
    },
    cache: false
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    var delay = 3000;
    setTimeout(function() {
      startRecords();
    }, delay);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### To remove elements that are not in the response from server.

Add the following right after `success: function(res) {`

```
var currentRows = $("[id^=records-row-]").toArray()
var currentRowsId = currentRows.map(function(row) { return row.id })
var resRows = res.map(function(row) { return "records-row-" + row.id })
var removeRows = currentRowsId.filter(function(rowId) { return resRows.indexOf(rowId) === -1 })
removeRows.forEach(function(rowId) { $("#" + rowId).remove() })
```

So that it looks like this

```
function startRecords() {
    $.ajax({
      url: URL,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        var currentRows = $("[id^=records-row-]").toArray()
        var currentRowsId = currentRows.map(function(row) { return row.id })
        var resRows = res.map(function(row) { return "records-row-" + row.id })
        var removeRows = currentRowsId.filter(function(rowId) { return resRows.indexOf(rowId) === -1 })
        removeRows.forEach(function(rowId) { $("#" + rowId).remove() })

        for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
          if ($("#records-row-" + res[i].id).length == 0) {
            $("#records-content tbody").prepend('<tr class="table-wrapper" id="records-row-' + res[i].id + '"><td class"" style="">' + res[i].content_1 + '</td><td class"" style="">' + res[i].content_2 + '</td></tr>');
          }
        }

        var delay = 3000;
        setTimeout(function() {
          startRecords();
        }, delay);
      },
      cache: false
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
      var delay = 3000;
      setTimeout(function() {
        startRecords();
      }, delay);
    });
  }
```

With comments

```
var currentRows = $("[id^=records-row-]").toArray() // get rows with id starting with "records-row-"
var currentRowsId = currentRows.map(function(row) { return row.id }) // extract ids from rows
var resRowsId = res.map(function(row) { return "records-row-" + row.id }) // extract ids from response that will be added to DOM
var removeRows = currentRowsId.filter(function(rowId) { return resRowsId.indexOf(rowId) === -1 }) // remove every element that is added to DOM and in response from server
removeRows.forEach(function(rowId) { $("#" + rowId).remove() }) // remove elements that are not in response and is added to DOM
```

### Alternative solution

`$("#records-content tbody").empty();` to remove every element each time the client fetches new data from server.